# Find a string within a cell using VBA

Tags: string, search, excel, vba

I have been driving myself mad with this for a day, searched high and low, and am probably trying to be too cute so am totally stuck.

I am trying to run a simple if then

If a cell contains "%" I'd like it to do one thing, and if not another.  For reasons I don't understand I can't get it to work out.  I've clearly taken a couple ideas from elsewhere but still can't get it to work.

Complicating factors- I don't want to run this on the whole column, just a table, so it is embedded in a larger sub using lots or relative ActiveCells.  I never know where in the A column I am going to run into the "% Change" so the Range always has to be variable.  I want VBA/VBE to do something different when it comes upon a cell with the "%" in it.  SO

Here is what the raw data looks like

```
Initial Value (6/30/06)

Value (12/31/06)

Net Additions (9/30/07)

Withdrawal (12/07)

Value (12/31/07)

Withdrawal (2008)

Value (12/31/08)

Addition (8/26/09)

Value (12/31/09)

Value (12/31/10)

Value (12/30/11)

Value (3/31/12)

% Change 1st Quarter

% Change Since Inception
```

But when I run the following it gets stuck in a bad loop where it should have pulled out into the "If Then" as opposed to the "Else" part of the sub.

```
Sub IfTest()
 'This should split the information in a table up into cells
 Dim Splitter() As String
 Dim LenValue As Integer     'Gives the number of characters in date string
 Dim LeftValue As Integer    'One less than the LenValue to drop the ")"
 Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
 Set rng = ActiveCell

Do While ActiveCell.Value <> Empty
    If InStr(rng, "%") = True Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Select
        Splitter = Split(ActiveCell.Value, "% Change")
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = Splitter(1)
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = "% Change"
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, -9).Select
    Else
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Select
        Splitter = Split(ActiveCell.Value, "(")
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = Splitter(0)
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        LenValue = Len(Splitter(1))
        LeftValue = LenValue - 1
        ActiveCell.Value = Left(Splitter(1), LeftValue)
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, -10).Select
    End If
Loop
End Sub
```

All help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I simplified your code to isolate the test for "%" being in the cell. Once you get that to work, you can add in the rest of your code.

Try this:

```
Option Explicit


Sub DoIHavePercentSymbol()
   Dim rng As Range

   Set rng = ActiveCell

   Do While rng.Value <> Empty
        If InStr(rng.Value, "%") = 0 Then
            MsgBox "I know nothing about percentages!"
            Set rng = rng.Offset(1)
            rng.Select
        Else
            MsgBox "I contain a % symbol!"
            Set rng = rng.Offset(1)
            rng.Select
        End If
   Loop

End Sub
```

`InStr` will return the number of times your search text appears in the string. I changed your `if` test to check for no matches first.

The message boxes and the `.Selects` are there simply for you to see what is happening while you are stepping through the code. Take them out once you get it working.

Comment: This is the simple piece of the puzzle I was missing.  I am still relatively new so hadn't thought (okay, maybe known :) about the ability to do the set rng.offset within the if.  That is great, and very very helpful.  I also had been using the true false as opposed to the = 0 for the InStr function, which I still don't totally get, but appreciate.  Thank you so very much!

Answer (score 0):

you never change the value of `rng` so it always points to the initial cell

copy the `Set rng = rng.Offset(1, 0)` to a new line before loop

also, your `InStr` test will always fail
`True` is -1, but the return from `InStr` will be greater than 0 when the string is found. change the test to remove = True

new code:

```
Sub IfTest()
 'This should split the information in a table up into cells
 Dim Splitter() As String
 Dim LenValue As Integer     'Gives the number of characters in date string
 Dim LeftValue As Integer    'One less than the LenValue to drop the ")"
 Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
 Set rng = ActiveCell

Do While ActiveCell.Value <> Empty
    If InStr(rng, "%") Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Select
        Splitter = Split(ActiveCell.Value, "% Change")
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = Splitter(1)
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = "% Change"
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, -9).Select
    Else
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Select
        Splitter = Split(ActiveCell.Value, "(")
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = Splitter(0)
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        LenValue = Len(Splitter(1))
        LeftValue = LenValue - 1
        ActiveCell.Value = Left(Splitter(1), LeftValue)
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, -10).Select
    End If
Set rng = rng.Offset(1, 0)
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Very good, thank you for the explanation on the inStr test!  That is very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

For a search routine you should look to use `Find`, `AutoFilter` or variant array approaches. Range loops are nomally too slow, worse again if they use `Select`

The code below will look for the strText variable in a user selected range, it then adds any matches to a range variable `rng2` which you can then further process

```
Option Explicit

Const strText As String = "%"

Sub ColSearch_DelRows()
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim rng3 As Range
    Dim cel1 As Range
    Dim cel2 As Range
    Dim strFirstAddress As String
    Dim lAppCalc As Long


    'Get working range from user
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng1 = Application.InputBox("Please select range to search for " & strText, "User range selection", Selection.Address(0, 0), , , , , 8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    With Application
        lAppCalc = .Calculation
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    Set cel1 = rng1.Find(strText, , xlValues, xlPart, xlByRows, , False)

    'A range variable - rng2 - is used to store the range of cells that contain the string being searched for
    If Not cel1 Is Nothing Then
        Set rng2 = cel1
        strFirstAddress = cel1.Address
        Do
            Set cel1 = rng1.FindNext(cel1)
            Set rng2 = Union(rng2, cel1)
        Loop While strFirstAddress <> cel1.Address
    End If

    If Not rng2 Is Nothing Then
        For Each cel2 In rng2
            Debug.Print cel2.Address & " contained " & strText
        Next
    Else
        MsgBox "No " & strText
    End If

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = lAppCalc
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This is going to be very helpful to me in the future, thank you!