# Excel VBA If Statement to Find Cells That Contain A String

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking to create an IF/Else statment in VBA that when run will return a True or False value based on if a cell contains a certain string of text.  So basically I want a True value returned if the cell contains the specified string or a False value if it does not contain the specified string.  This formula needs to run down a range of cells not just one if that makes a difference.  I'm thinking I need to use the InStr function, but I'm not 100% sure if that is correct or how to implement it.  I am fairly new to VBA so any help I can get would be greatly appreciated as I have been stuck on this for several hours.

Thank You

Comment: Try `mBool = Range("A1").Value Like "*stringtofind*"`

Comment: You can use InStr but that function returns the number of the character where your string is found. So you need to write `if instr("bar","foobar") > 0 then found=true else found=false`

Comment: So what function would be the best then for retuning a Boolean True/False value based on cells contains the specified string?  I would like to be able to have all of these True/False values next to their corresponding cells to show which cells contain the specified text string.

Comment: I think a formula is better here, see: [Cell contains specific text](https://exceljet.net/formula/cell-contains-specific-text) - `=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(substring,text))`

Comment: Will all of these functions/formulas return a True/False value?

Comment: @Gordon you can write this in one line using FunctionName = (InStr("foobar", "bar") > 0)

Comment: @JoeObe25 there's a couple of solutions here. As this is for your homework why not try all of them and see if you can learn what they're doing

Comment: @JoeObe25 - Your teacher would not have asked you to do this assignment if they hadn't already taught you enough to answer it.  Go back over your course notes, or review what was taught in class, and you should be able to come up with the answer yourself.  And, if you can't, then the aim of the assignment will have been achieved by showing the teacher that you can't.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find a string within a cell using VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904012/find-a-string-within-a-cell-using-vba)

Answer (score 1):

Why use VBA? An expression in cell can return True/False.

`=ISNUMBER(FIND("something",A1))`

I tested @3vts code and it runs but the output is wrong. This version works:

```
Sub FindString()
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A100")
For Each cell In rng.Cells
    If InStr(1, cell, "text to find") > 0 Then
        cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = True
    Else
        cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = False
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

I certainly hope you learned something in spite of the work was done for you.

Comment: It's for a homework assignment it's required that I use VBA for this

Comment: @JoeObe25 If it's for a homework assignment, **YOU** should be writing it.  We are not doing your course - you are!

Comment: Okay, then as shown by Tom's comment, a one-liner will return True/False, no need for If Then Else structure. Show your entire procedure if you have more issues. As YowE3K states, we don't do your homework for you. You need to make attempt. Use the macro recorder to help generate code that can be learned from and modified.

Comment: I'm not trying to have anyone write the code for me it's just all of the suggested code I have tried and found doesn't include an If/Else and that's what the teacher's skeleton code so I was hoping to get poninted in the right direction

Comment: Then show what you have created so for as a custom user defined function (UDF). Gordan gave you an If Then Else in his comment.

Comment: I believe I got several of the codes to run the only trouble I am having now is trying to figure out how to have True/False values appear in the column next to the cells that I am searching for the string in. Any ideas I'm lost

Answer (score 1):

Well this is a very badly asked question but I think everyone has needed some help at some point in life. That being said, here is the code you are asking for

```
Sub FindString()
'Declare the range
Dim rng As Range
'Assign the range to find
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A100")
'Loop though each cell
For Each cell In rng.Cells
    'Check if cell has the string and set text 
    'of the next column to True or False
    cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = IIf(InStr(1, cell, "stringToFind"), "True", "False")
Next
End Sub
```

Give it a try and let me know your comments

Comment: I believe I got your code to run the only trouble I am having now is trying to figure out how to have True/False values appear in the column next to the cells that I am searching for the string in, instead of message boxes appearing.

Comment: That's basically a copycat. I improved my code to use a ternary operator.

Answer (score 0):

May be the below one can help you, It gives you whether the excel contains the Word.

```
Dim ra As Range

Set ra = Cells.Find(What:=Word, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False)

If ra Is Nothing Then
    'False (Not Found)
Else
    'True (Found)
End If
```